# JavaScript function for matching regular expression

Tags: javascript, asp.net, regex

I have got a textbox on the ASP.net webform and the expected value is in the format `AA000000`. 
I am using a custom validator to call a Javascript function to validate the text using a regular expression. But this isn't working yet. 
Please advice.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPassportNumber" runat="server" Visible="True" Width="576px" AutoPostBack="True" ControlToValidate="txtIdentityNumber"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="valRequiredPassportNumber" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Passport number is required." ControlToValidate="txtPassportNumber" ValidateRequestMode="Enabled" Font-Italic="True" ForeColor="Red" SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:CustomValidator ID="valCustomPassportNumber" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please provide a valid Passport number." ControlToValidate="txtPassportNumber" ClientValidationFunction="validatePassportNumber" Font-Italic="True" ForeColor="Red" SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

JS

```js
< script >
  function validatePassportNumber(oSrc, args) {
    if (document.getElementById("txtPassportNumber").value != "") {
      var inputString = document.getElementById("txtPassportNumber").value;
      //var pattern = new RegExp("/[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{6}/");
      var pattern = /[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{6}/;
      if (pattern.test(inputString) == true)
        args.IsValid = true
      else
        args.IsValid = false
    }
  } <script >
```

Comment: Better use `/^[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{6}$/`

Comment: @S.Kablar nope doesn't work with this as well

Answer (score 0):

Use this :`^[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{6}$`
in javascript:  `/^[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{6}$/gm`

```
^           : First of line  
[a-zA-Z]{2} : any character with length 2  
\d{6}       : any digit(number) with length 6  
$           : End of line
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uJWGaH/1)

Answer (score 0):

You might use this regex:

[`^[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{6}$`](https://regex101.com/r/SW6Li5/1)

```
var pattern = /^[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{6}$/;
```

That would match

```
^        # The beginning of the string
[A-Z]{2} # 2 Uppercase characters
[0-9]{6} # 6 digits
$        # The end of the string
```